# Pandas convert time format

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert the following time format to a valid date time format for my graphs.

2020-05-06T08:49:23.004+10:00

So far I've been removing the +10:00 in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `pandas.to_datetime(time)`, where `time = 2020-05-06T08:49:23.004+10:00`?

Comment: It has to be something on your side, code
`
import pandas as pd
time = "2020-05-06T08:49:23.004+10:00"
print(pd.to_datetime(time))
`
Outputs `2020-05-06 08:49:23.004000+10:00` as a datetime object. I have pandas 1.0.3.